# Is there a way to use a Typescript function definition as a complete type in JSDoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I have a `types.d.ts` in which I provide typings for the end users of the library. One of the types looks like the following:

```js
export type Helpers = {
    foo(param: ComplexType, param2: ComplexType2): ComplexType & SomeIntersectionTypes;

    bar(param: ComplexType, param2: ComplexType2): ComplexType & SomeIntersectionTypes;

    baz(param: ComplexType, param2: ComplexType2): ComplexType & SomeIntersectionTypes;
}
```

Now, in my JS file I'd like to reference these types with JSDoc so I get a bit of type hinting/warnings if I ever break them. Something like:

```js
/**
 * @type {typeof import('path/to/types.js').Helpers.foo}
 */
foo(param, param2) { ... }
```

This just leads to the following error in my editor, though it seems like this syntax (in the JSDoc) is entirely incorrect anyways:

```
[tsserver 8030] [E] The type of a function declaration must match the function's signature.
```

Having to separately import the param types and form the return types of these functions seems silly. I'd just like to type the entire function given this existing definition in a `.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the correct way to do this seems to be the following:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('path/to/types.js').Helpers['foo']}
 */
foo(param, param2) { ... }
```

I'm still a bit unsure why we need to access `foo` in the way that we do, but the type is correctly found and checked against using this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for detailing your solution journey. I was having a similar problem. Turns out JSDoc for whatever reason doesn't support using "@type" with `export function X(...) { ... }` style exports, but does support the more verbose `export const X = function(...) { ... }` style exports. It could be that I'm using ESM (with `{ "type": "module" }` in `package.json`) in a project without also including a jsconfig/tsconfig file, which seems to make TypeScript/JSDoc fall back to the misbehaving Node10 resolution strategy.